# How to join a table with multiple columns without multiple join statements in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I have a table with the following structure.

```
Top|Second|Mid   |Bot
1  | 2    | 3    | 4
1  | 2    | 7    | null
1  | 5    | 6    | null
1  | 8    | null | null
1  | 9    |10    | 11
```

Here 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 are `Emp Numbers`. I have another table which has 2 columns `Emp No`, `Name`

```
Emp No | Name
1      | A
2      | B
3      | C
```

And so on.

I want to join the names table with the top table and get the names for each employees. Is there a way I can join it to get names for all employees without having to join it with each column again and again? I know it can be done if I join it with Top then with Second then with Mid and then with Bot, but I am looking for a better solution if it is possible.

```
Top|TopName |Second| SecName | Mid   | MidName | Bot | BotName
1  | A      | 2    | B       | 3     | C       | 4   |  D
1  | A      | 2    | B       | 7     | G       | null| null
1  | A      | 5    | E       | 6     | F       | null| null
1  | A      | 8    | H       | null  | null    | null| null
1  | A      | 9    | I       | 10    | J       |  11 | K
```

Comment: there is none, so go for it

Comment: The table must be joined on the values from each column, you can either write a query with multiple joins & aliases or use a correlated subquery for each `name` column.

Comment: The values in separate columns in one row are independent. So you need an independent names table copy to be joined to each separate column for to "decode" it.